# iOS 14.4.2 seems to disable video autoplay

Tags: ios, html5-video, vimeo, autoplay, vimeo-player

I've noticed that with the recent update to iOS 14.4.2, all of my autoplay video stopped autoplaying. Everything worked just fine on the previous version. This goes for HTML 5 videos, as well as vimeo embeds with their player.js. I've checked other websites using HTML 5, which used to previously work, and all of their videos stopped autoplaying.

With HTML, I'm using the code below to autoplay:

```
<video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" playsinline="" id="hosting-video">
<source src="LINK" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

For Vimeo, I'm using this code:

```
<iframe src="LINK?background=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;byline=0&amp;title=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay" muted="muted" data-ready="true"></iframe>
```

I couldn't find anything on this online. Is anyone else experiecing this on iOS 14.4.2? If so, is there anything I can do to play video automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone's wondering, the videos work just fine. Apparently, enabling battery saver on iphone disables autoplay videos.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing autoplay and playsInline with below code :

```
autoPlay='autoplay' playsInline='playsinline'
```

Hope it works for you.