# Autoplay in iframe (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I have an element in HTML:

```
<iframe allow="autoplay;" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zyZAMR56mXY?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;start=2&amp;amp;mute=1" width="640"></iframe>
```

This element is on my web site. Everything is working, but if I open web page on IOS autoplay does not work. Can some one please help?

I tried to right some scripts for that tag on JavaScript. I used play(), or other logical code and tried to change the src attribute, but it did not work.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963931/ios-14-4-2-seems-to-disable-video-autoplay

Comment: Did you try more than one device? That's usually a good start. Then you know whether it's something particular to the first device that's causing your problem.